# How to make bit wise XNOR in C

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, xor, bitwise-xor

I'm having trouble writing a bitwise `XNOR` function with at most 7 `~` and `|` operators. Example: `bitXnor(6, -5) = 2`. How do I do this without `&`?

So far I have this:

```
int bitXnor(int x, int y) {
  return ~(~x | ~y);
```

but I'm getting the error:

```
ERROR: Test bitXnor(-2147483648[0x80000000],-2147483648[0x80000000]) failed...
...Gives -2147483648[0x80000000]. Should be -1[0xffffffff]
```

Comment: In addition to various good answers, to avoid potential issues using _signed_ types with bit-wise operators, consider using `unsigned`.

Answer (score 5):

Now is a good time to learn De Morgan's laws, i.e.

```
~ (x & y) == (~x | ~y)
```

An XNOR is

```
(~a & ~b) | (a & b)
```

rewrite by adding double inverts (aka double NOTs) to get

```
~~(~a & ~b) | ~~(a & b)
```

and then rewrite using De Morgan

```
~(~~a | ~~b) | ~(~a | ~b)
```

and reduce the first part (i.e. remove the double inverts)

```
~(a | b) | ~(~a | ~b)
```

That's an XNOR using 7 `~` and `|`

Source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws

BTW:

Using the same principle De Morgans law can lead to

```
(~a & ~b) | (a & b)
```

to

```
~~((~a & ~b) | (a & b))
```

to

```
~(~(~a & ~b) & ~(a & b))
```

for an XNOR constructed using only `~` and `&`. In this case 8 operators is needed.

EDIT:

As pointed out by user "chux - Reinstate Monica" it is possible to do it with only `~` and `&` and **7 operators**.

For instance by adding a few extra steps like:

```
(~a & ~b) | (a & b)
```

to

```
~~((~a & ~b) | (a & b))
```

to

```
~(~(~a & ~b) & ~(a & b))
```

to

```
~((a | b) & (~a | ~b))
```

to

```
~(((a & (~a | ~b)) | (b & (~a | ~b)))
```

to

```
~((a & ~a) | (a & ~b) | (b & ~a) | (b & ~b))
```

to

```
~((a & ~b) | (b & ~a))
```

to

```
~(a & ~b) & ~(b & ~a)
```

Now it's down to 7 operators.

Comment: "In this case 8 operators is needed" --> With `~(~(~a & ~b) & ~(a & b))`, I'd expect we can remove the outside `~` by inverting one argument like `(~(a & ~b) & ~(~a & b))`.  Now back to 7 operators.

Answer (score 2):

A XNOR B is true if and only if A and B are both false or both true. Expressing this directly gives:

> A XNOR B = ((not A) and (not B)) or (A and B)

In order to use only "not" and "or", we can use the logical identities (De Morgan's laws):

> not (A or B) = (not A) and (not B)
>
> not (A and B) = (not A) or (not B)

as well as

> not (not A) = A

Thus,

> A XNOR B = not (A or B) or not ((not A) or (not B))

Translating this into C, we get:

```
int bitXnor(int x, int y) {
  return ~(x | y) | ~(~x | ~y);
}
```

The OP code misses the first part of the expression.

Answer (score 0):

XNOR has the following truths:

0 XNOR 0 = 1
0 XNOR 1 = 0
1 XNOR 0 = 0
1 XNOR 1 = 1

equivalent to ~(x ^ y)

To do this using only ~ and |

Your logic is ~(~x | ~y) doesn't work logically for the case of 0 XNOR 0, as  `1 | 1` is `1` and `~1` is 0.  You've implemented the AND gate.

If I'm not mistaken, you can do XNOR using (x | ~y) & (~x | y)

but we need to add in your AND gate.

in one expression:
`~(~(x | ~y)) | (~(~x | y))`

EDIT: yes, this leaves us with 8 operators.
I believe can fortunately be simplified to:

`~(x | y) |  ~(~x | ~y)`

Comment: I think it has to be return ~ (~a | ~b) for the logic to work but that would be 8 operators, like the one line expression. I'm not sure how to cut it down to 7

Comment: sorry, I think I left on an extra ~.

Comment: What would be the extra one?

Answer (score -1):

Negate (`~`) either parameter and XOR them (`^`)

```
int bitXnor(int x, int y) { 
  return x ^ ~y;
}
```

Comment: I'm guessing that's not allowed in this assignment

Comment: Thanks for helping but how would I do this only using ~ and |? The logic works out in my solution, but it doesn't pass the test

Comment: Eric, `x ^ ~y` does indeed do the xnor bit-wise operation.  Perhaps now show how `^` can be done with only 6 or less `~`, `|` operations as request by OP?